# Emulate Gpio input on Raspberry Pi for testing

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, gpio

I have a python script running on my RPi. It uses the Gpiozero library (that's really great by the way).

For testing purposes i was wondering if it was possible to emulate GPIO states somehow (say emulate pressing a button) and have it picked up by the gpiozero library.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

TLDNR: Yes, it is possible.

I am not aware of any already prepared solution that can help you achieve what you want to do. Hence I found it very interesting whether it is feasible at all.

I was looking a while for a seam which can be used to stub the GPIO features and I have found that gpiozero [uses](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/python-gpiozero/blob/0c03429122eb5dfd0b8264f56976524ae62ab4ee/gpiozero/devices.py) `GPIOZERO_PIN_FACTORY` environmental  variable to pick a backend. The plan is to write own pin factory, that will provide possibility to test other scripts.

NOTE: Please treat my solution as a proof of concept. It is far from being production ready.

The idea is to get GPIO states out of script under test scope. My solution uses env variable `RPI_STUB_URL` to get path of unix socket which will be used to communicate with the `stub controller`.

I have introduced very simple one request/response per connection protocol:

- "GF {pin}\n" - ask what is the current function of the `pin`. Stub does not validate the response, but I would expect "input", "output" to be used.
- "SF {pin} {function}\n" - request change of the pin's current function. Stub does not validate the function, bu I would expect "input", "output" to be used. Stub expects "OK" as a response.
- "GS {pin}\n" - ask what is the current state of the `pin`. Stub expects values "0" or "1" as a response.
- "SS {pin} {value|]n" - request change of the pin's current state. Stub expects "OK" as a response.

My "stub package" contains following files:

```
- setup.py # This file is needed in every package, isn't it?
- rpi_stub/ 
   - __init__.py # This file collects entry points
   - stubPin.py # This file implements stub backend for gpiozero
   - controller.py # This file implements server for my stub
   - trigger.py # This file implements client side feature of my stub
```

Let's start with `setup.py` content:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="Raspberry PI GPIO stub",
    version="0.1",
    description="Package with stub plugin for gpiozero library",
    packages=find_packages(),
        install_requires = ["gpiozero"],
    include_package_data=True,
    entry_points="""
[console_scripts]
stub_rpi_controller=rpi_stub:controller_main
stub_rpi_trigger=rpi_stub:trigger_main
[gpiozero_pin_factories]
stub_rpi=rpi_stub:make_stub_pin
"""
)
```

It defines two console_scripts entry points one for controller and one for trigger. And one pin factory for gpiozero.

Now `rpi_stub/__init__.py`:

```
import rpi_stub.stubPin 
from rpi_stub.controller import controller_main
from rpi_stub.trigger import trigger_main

def make_stub_pin(number):
    return stubPin.StubPin(number)
```

It is rather simple file.

File `rpi_stub/trigger.py`:

```
import socket
import sys

def trigger_main():
   socket_addr = sys.argv[1]
   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   sock.connect(socket_addr)
   request = "{0}\n".format(" ".join(sys.argv[2:]))
   sock.sendall(request.encode())
   data = sock.recv(1024)
   sock.close()
   print(data.decode("utf-8"))
```

`trigger` allows you to make your own request. You can use it to check what is the state of GPIO pin or change it.

File `rpi_stub/controller.py`:

```
import socketserver
import sys

functions = {}
states = {}

class MyHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):

    def _respond(self, response):
        print("Sending response: {0}".format(response))
        self.wfile.write(response.encode())

    def _handle_get_function(self, data):
        print("Handling get_function: {0}".format(data))
        try:
          self._respond("{0}".format(functions[data[0]]))
        except KeyError:
          self._respond("input")

    def _handle_set_function(self, data):
        print("Handling set_function: {0}".format(data))
        functions[data[0]] = data[1]
        self._respond("OK")

    def _handle_get_state(self, data):
        print("Handling get_state: {0}".format(data))
        try:
          self._respond("{0}".format(states[data[0]]))
        except KeyError:
          self._respond("0")

    def _handle_set_state(self, data):
        print("Handling set_state: {0}".format(data))
        states[data[0]] = data[1]
        self._respond("OK")

    def handle(self):
        data = self.rfile.readline()
        print("Handle: {0}".format(data))
        data = data.decode("utf-8").strip().split(" ")

        if data[0] == "GF":
            self._handle_get_function(data[1:])
        elif data[0] == "SF":
            self._handle_set_function(data[1:])
        elif data[0] == "GS":
            self._handle_get_state(data[1:])
        elif data[0] == "SS":
            self._handle_set_state(data[1:])
        else:
            self._respond("Not understood")

def controller_main():
    socket_addr = sys.argv[1]
    server = socketserver.UnixStreamServer(socket_addr, MyHandler)
    server.serve_forever()
```

This file contains the simplest server I was able to write.

And the most complicated file `rpi_stub/stubPin.py`:

```
from gpiozero.pins import Pin
import os
import socket
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def dummy_func():
   pass

def edge_detector(pin):
   print("STUB: Edge detector for pin: {0} spawned".format(pin.number))
   while pin._edges != "none":
      new_state = pin._get_state()
      print("STUB: Edge detector for pin {0}: value {1} received".format(pin.number, new_state))
      if new_state != pin._last_known:
          print("STUB: Edge detector for pin {0}: calling callback".format(pin.number))
          pin._when_changed()
      pin._last_known = new_state 
      sleep(1)
   print("STUB: Edge detector for pin: {0} ends".format(pin.number))


class StubPin(Pin):

    def __init__(self, number):
        super(StubPin, self).__init__()
        self.number = number
        self._when_changed = dummy_func
        self._edges = "none"
        self._last_known = 0

    def _make_request(self, request):
        server_address = os.getenv("RPI_STUB_URL", None)
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.connect(server_address)
        sock.sendall(request.encode())
        data = sock.recv(1024)
        sock.close()
        return data.decode("utf-8")

    def _get_function(self):
        response = self._make_request("GF {pin}\n".format(pin=self.number))
        return response;

    def _set_function(self, function):
        response = self._make_request("SF {pin} {function}\n".format(pin=self.number, function=function))
        if response != "OK":
          raise Exception("STUB Not understood", response)

    def _get_state(self):
        response = self._make_request("GS {pin}\n".format(pin=self.number))
        if response == "1":
           return 1
        else:
           return 0

    def _set_pull(self, value):
         pass

    def _set_edges(self, value):
         print("STUB: set edges called: {0}".format(value))
         if self._edges == "none" and value != "none":
             self._thread = Thread(target=edge_detector,args=(self,))
             self._thread.start()
         if self._edges != "none" and value == "none":
             self._edges = value;
             self._thread.join()
         self._edges = value
         pass

    def _get_when_changed(self, value):
         return self._when_changed

    def _set_when_changed(self, value):
         print("STUB: set when changed: {0}".format(value))
         self._when_changed = value

    def _set_state(self, value):
        response = self._make_request("SS {pin} {value}\n".format(pin=self.number, value=value))
        if response != "OK":
          raise Exception("Not understood", response)
```

The file defines `StubPin` which extends `Pin` from [gpiozero](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RPi-Distro/python-gpiozero/2e7543d3151ee048facb79c666ba5ea5053b33c4/gpiozero/pins/__init__.py). It defines all functions that was mandatory to be overriden. It also contains very naive edge detection as it was needed for `gpio.Button` to work.

Let's make a demo :). Let's create virtualenv which gpiozero and my package installed:

```
$ virtualenv -p python3 rpi_stub_env
[...] // virtualenv successfully created
$ source ./rpi_stub_env/bin/activate
(rpi_stub_env)$ pip install gpiozero
[...] // gpiozero installed
(rpi_stub_env)$ python3 setup.py install
[...] // my package installed
```

Now let's create stub controller (open in other terminal etc.):

```
(rpi_stub_env)$ stub_rpi_controller /tmp/socket.sock
```

I will use the following script `example.py`:

```
from gpiozero import Button                                                                                         
from time import sleep                                                                                              

button = Button(2)

while True:
    if button.is_pressed:
       print("Button is pressed")
    else:
       print("Button is not pressed")
    sleep(1)
```

Let's execute it:
     (rpi_stub_env)$ RPI_STUB_URL=/tmp/socket.sock GPIOZERO_PIN_FACTORY=stub_rpi python example.py

By default the script prints that the button is pressed. Now let's press the button:

```
(rpi_stub_env)$ stub_rpi_trigger /tmp/socket.sock SS 2 1
```

Now the script should print that the button is not pressed. If you execute the following command it will be pressed again:

```
(rpi_stub_env)$ stub_rpi_trigger /tmp/socket.sock SS 2 0
```

I hope it will help you.